# Convert a string to object javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```
Id: {
    editable: false,
    nullable: true
},
CustomerID: {
    editable: true,
    type: Integer
},
CompanyName: {
    editable: true,
    type: String
},
ContactName: {
    editable: true,
    type: String
}
```

Hi, is there a way in javascript or jquery where I could convert this String into an Object?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you get that string?

Comment: JSON doesn't support function values (like String or Integer. also not supported in all browsers (versions)

Comment: That string should be dynamic, I read fields from a database table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is strictly the format of the string then it's invalid JSON. However, you *can* get around this issue with judicious use of `eval()`:

```
eval('myobj = {' + stringifiedObject + '};');
```

---

As clarification, the reason you cannot use `JSON.parse()` here is that the JSON specification requires that all keys are quoted.

```
JSON.parse('{ ID: 1 }');   // Generates an exception: Invalid character
JSON.parse('{ "ID": 1 }'); // Returns object: { ID: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Based on the @Phylogenesis answer but without the `eval`.**

Wrap the -almost- object and then run a `JSON.parse`.

```
var myObj;

stringifiedObject = '{' + stringifiedObject + '}';
myObj = JSON.parse(stringifiedObject);
```

Note:
*If you don't know the origin (or format) of the string you'd like to pase, then you can wrap the `JSON.parse` line between a `try..catch()` statement.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. The JSON specification requires that key names are quoted: `{ "Id": { "editable": false, "nullable": true }, ...}`. Running `JSON.parse()` on your example will generate an exception.

Comment: @Phylogenesis you're right, your answer is definitely better then.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of both existing answers

```
var new_string = JSON.parse((string.trim().charAt(0)!=='{')?('{'+string+'}'):string);
```

Assuming string is your input, and new_string is your output

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you,

```
var mystring="[Id: {
    editable: false,
    nullable: true
},
CustomerID: {
    editable: true,
    type: Integer
},
CompanyName: {
    editable: true,
    type: String
},
ContactName: {
    editable: true,
    type: String
}]";

var obj1 = JSON.parse(mystring);

OR 

var obj2= eval('(' + mystring+ ')');
```